# Magnetism: Converting formula into linear expression

Tags: electromagnetism

I recently conducted an experiment aimed at calculating the Earth's magnetic field.
A compass was placed inside a coil and the apparatus was aligned east-west. When current was applied to the coil, the deflection of the compass was the vector addition of the Earth's magnetic field and the magnetic field created by the coil.

To negate the error, I took multiple measurements with constant current and varied the compass position in relation to the coil. Recording the deflection angle and distance from the coil.

I have the following formulas the relate the deflection angle to the distance $x$ from the coil:

$$\tan \theta = \frac{Bc}{Be}$$

$$ Bc = \frac{\mu NIR^2}{2{(R^2+x^2)}^{3/2}} $$

I have found articles on similar experiments and it's mentioned that these two formulas can be combined into a linear equation: $$ Y = mX + A$$

My guess is that $ Y = \theta $ and $ X = x $. This function could then be graphed and the slope would give a more accurate result of $Be$

However, there was no guidance on how to combine these formulas into the linear form. Why does this offer better accuracy? Can anyone point me in the right direction on this transformation?

Comment: Your suggestion $Y=\theta$ and $X=x$ yields a linear relation only for very small angles and $x$, i.e. in a linear approximation, which may not be helpful.
You could set $Y=\tan\theta$ and $X=\frac{1}{\left(R^2+x^2\right)^{3/2}}$ - which you can compute from the experimental results - and by the above formulas should obtain a linear relationship with $m$ proportional to the inverse of the earth's magnetic field.

Comment: Thanks @kricheli. Very helpful!